# using sed in bash while loop

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script with while loop:

```
DATA=$1
TMP_FILE=tmp_$RANDOM
cat $DATA.symbols | while read SYMBOL;
    cat $DATA.symbols | while read SYMBOL;
    do
            grep $SYMBOL $DATA.tape > $TMP_FILE
            TOTAL=`cat $TMP_FILE | wc -l`
            FIRST=`awk '{print $3}' $TMP_FILE | head -1`
            LAST=`awk '{print $3}' $TMP_FILE | tail -1`
            SEC=`bc <<< "scale=3;$TOTAL/(24*60*60)"`
            MIN=`bc <<< "scale=3;$TOTAL/(24*60)"`
            HOUR=`bc <<< "scale=3;$TOTAL/24"`
            echo "Total ticks for $SYMBOL: $TOTAL, first tick at: $FIRST, last tick at: $LAST, avarage 1 sec: $SEC, avarage 1 min: $MIN, avarage 1 hour: $HOUR" >> $DATA.stats
            sed -i 's/\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]//' $DATA.stats
            sed -i 's/\+0300//' $DATA.stats
    done
```

But the loop stops at the first row when there is 2r rows.
If I comment out sed command all works. Is there any way to use sed whith -i option in while loop ?

Comment: You might consider explaining exactly what you're trying to do...

Comment: Of course. I read lines from $DATA.symbols file. After that in loop I make calculations for captured data and save it to file. The issue is that I need to replace/remove some strings after that. So I'm using sed to do that. I specified "-i" to save changes in the same file.

Comment: Your script has 2 lines with `cat $DATA.symbols | while read SYMBOL;`.
I think that is just a copy/paste error.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It is better to clean the `$DATA.stats` with `sed -i ...` outside the loop, that way all lines are checked only once. Or use sed in a pipe after the echo before adding to the file (do not write incorrect data to the file and patch when finished but write correct data to the file).

Comment: I'm afraid Bash is a rather terrible language for this kind of manipulation. You could try for example a `with open(path) as file_pointer` loop in Python with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to be able to do accurate date/time zone manipulation.

Comment: Some versions of sed need an argument with `-i`, e.g. `sed -i '' s/A/a/ file.txt`

Comment: Using `sed -i` in a loop is inefficient. If we had a better understanding of your goals, it would probably be rather easy to devise a way to avoid this antipattern.

Comment: You have 2 `while` statements yet only one `do`....